# From TypeDataset to Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sybase, strongly-typed-dataset

I am working on window application developed using SCSF and we are using sybase database. As practise we create typedataset in the .net project and then populate them using framework method and for all the sql statement we write stored procedure in the database.

So we have type dataset in memory so I am using linq to select records from datatable. Can I step one step further and use something related to Entity Framework?

Can it reduce my work? I don't have hands-on experience with Entity Framework but can you suggest something in this scenario?

Thanks,
Denish

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework uses similar concepts as the type datasets except for:

1. The ability to have a class structure that is not exactly the same as the table structure (e.g. class hierarchy, splitting tables into multiple classes, joining tables into one class).
2. The ability to use LINQ to perform queries in the database instead of in memory.

Entity framework also lets you map results of stored procedures to classes and bring results into memory if you need to run a query that is faster in memory or not translatable to SQL.

For most SQL queries the LINQ to Entity will be effective enough, so you will probably end up writing less stored procedures.

You will have to learn how to use EF and LINQ effectively and use can use 3rd party tools such as [Entity Framework Profiler](http://efprof.com/) to help you.